# Git repository in subdirectory is reading .gitignore from parent directory

Tags: git, macos, gitignore, osx-elcapitan

I like to keep my home directory under version control, to track changes to Bash startup files, various config files, etc.  I have a ~/.gitignore file which ignores everything, followed by various lines which tell Git exactly what files I want to track:

```
/*
!.bash*
.bash_history
!.ssh/
.ssh/*
!.ssh/config
```

Then I have some Git repositories hosted within my home directory, say ~/dev/project/.

Here's my problem.  On my Linux box, I have no problem with these two repositories -- they don't conflict.

```
[~/dev/project] $ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/dev/project/.git/
[~/dev/project] $ touch test
[~/dev/project] $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit    
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
test    
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

But on my Mac laptop (El Capitan), they do conflict.  The repo in the subdirectory is reading the .gitignore from the home directory, and the first rule, to ignore everything ("/*") is being applied:

```
[~/dev/project] $ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/dev/project/.git/
[~/dev/project] $ touch test
[~/dev/project] $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit    
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
[~/dev/project] $ mv ~/.gitignore ~/.gitignore.tmp
[~/dev/project] $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit    
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
test
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.  Linux box is Debian (stable), Git v.2.1.4; El Capitan is Git v. 2.6.2 (latest).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the file ~/.gitignore was being used as a global excludes file by git, but the property was not set in the global config (~/.gitconfig) nor the local config (~/.git/config), but somewhere else, somehow (a "superglobal"?):

```
$ git config --global --list | grep "core\.excludesfile"

$ git config --local --list | grep "core\.excludesfile"

$ git config --list | grep "core\.excludesfile"
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
```

By overriding it "globally", I fixed it:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ""
$ git config --list | grep "core\.excludesfile"
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.excludesfile=
```